# SN2 reaction with alkyl bromide and pentanenitrile?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Is it possible to do a Friedel-Crafts alkylation on a plain alkane such as the one I've attached below, or is it only reserved for EArS mechanisms?

Also, I was wondering what would happen if I tried this reaction with another halogen on the starting substrate (if I had 1-bromoethane for example)...

[image: Substrate is an ethane, reactant is 1-chloropropane (reacts with AlCl3), product is 2-methylpentane.]

Edit 1: I realize now that the top reaction doesn't make sense. Rather than a Friedel-Crafts Alkylation, I think I found a mechanism to make this type of reaction work (SN2) with Br as a leaving group and CN as a strong nucleophile, but I'm not sure...

[image: 1-bromoethane as the substrate, reacts with butyronitrile; the reagent, to form (S)-2-ethyl-3-methylbutanenitrile as the product]

Edit 2: I miscounted the carbons.
[image: 1-bromoethane as the substrate, reacts with pentanenitrile; the reagent, to form (S)-2-ethyl-3-methylbutanenitrile as the product]

Edit 3: This is what I understand, from the suggestions given...

[image: 1-bromoethane as the substrate, reacts with isobutyronitrile; the reagent to form (S)-2-ethyl-3-methylbutanenitrile as the product + an enantiomer]

Comment: I assume you've seen the FC alkylation mechanism before. How do you think it could be extended to this? Can you draw out a proposed mechanism?

Comment: For a moment, I thought it were an example of ~Wurtz-Fittig reaction~, but your reaction does not include elemental sodium.

Comment: yes, I don't think that my first attempt makes sense. I tried another mechanism in my edit to form a different product.

Comment: The edit also does not make sense. Count the number of carbons.

Comment: oops I missed that. but can that mechanism still work?

Comment: I still don't think so. There's branching in the product and not in your substrates. The general reaction works, but not the specific one you wrote.

Comment: You need strong base to generate an anion next to the -CN then the general reaction can work (but not the example you have drawn)

Comment: Why are you showing a dashed C-CN bond? Any product will be a racemate as described.

Comment: @user55119 that was the stereochemistry of the given product

Comment: @Waylander Oh ok, I thought that the CN- could act as the strong base, can I add any strong base like NaOH for example or...?

Comment: @Zhe sorry, I'm not understanding, my logic was that the pentanenitrile would rearrange to form the product that I put (like as a major product)... is it my substrate that is wrong? or am I missing something else?

Comment: @chemquestionquest09  NaOH is not strong enough, try lithium diisopropylamide

Comment: If you do the reaction the way you describe, then only 50% of the product will have the correct stereochemistry. Your alkylation should have a normal line.

Comment: @user55119 I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'normal line'... this might be wrong, but I thought that it would simply be an SN2 reaction (not an alkylation) since I'm not using Cl, Br etc. nor AlCl3. -Referring to Edit 2

Comment: A "normal line" is like all other single bonds in your structures. Such a bond is the equivalent of 50% dashed and 50% bold, a racemate. The alkylation you are doing will not give only one of them.

Comment: You need to re-edit the placement and number of carbons in your nitrile reactants.

Comment: @user55119 ok, I'll try and I'll make another edit, thank you for your help!

Comment: Edit 3 is still wrong. The starting nitrile is wrong. You started with 6 carbons and end with 7. Would you like an Answer?

Comment: @user55119 oh ok... and yes please I'm really unsure where exactly I'm going wrong. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are having some difficulty with this synthesis. The suggestion in the Comments that you employ lithium diisopropylamide (LDA) to generate the anion of a nitrile is a wise one. The anion is usually formed a -78<sup>o</sup>C in tetrahydrofuran (THF). The bromide is added and the reaction mixture is allowed to warm to ambient temperature. There are two possible bonds that can be made in what is termed a retrosynthetic analysis. One by method A and another by method B. The bonds formed are shown in red in structures **2**. Method A is better than method B because an S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction is being conducted on a primary halide, ethyl bromide. Method B requires an S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction on a secondary halide, 2-bromopropane, a process that is hindered and in competition with an E2 elimination that would produce propene **4** and the starting nitrile **3**. Nitrile **2** must be a racemate given its method of formation. It is comprised of equal amounts of the two enantiomers, (*R*)-**2** and (*S*)-**2**. By the methods employed here, a single enantiomer cannot be formed. Thus, a "normal bond" (not dashed nor bold) is shown in nitriles **2**.

[image]

Comment: yes, I am struggling with this, thank you so much. so in order to get the desired product I absolutely have to start with the nitrile on my substrate?

Comment: If you must start with nitrile 3, add the anion to acetone and dehydrate to the conjugated nitrile. Then the double bond has to be reduced without affecting the nitrile. Perhaps Pd/C and H2 in ETOAc at atmospheric pressure. But that's another question.

Comment: thank you!! I really appreciate all your help!